# send MKMapView to back in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mkmapview

I have `MKMapView` on which and I want to display `UIView` dynamically over the `MapView` but view never comes to the front. So, what is the solution to this problem?

Comment: Please explain your exact problem in more detail... like whether you just want to show another view on top of the map view or you want to show your view as a part of the map etc..

Comment: @Pritam Salunkhe please put your code .

Comment: Either set z index of your uiview as nsintegermax so that it always comes to top or if that is a part of mapview then better set it in an annotation view. If you still didn't solve it then you might need to send us your code block so that we can check here whats wrong with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call the below method. Where you are want show UIView.

```
yourViewObject.layer.zPosition = 1
```

Comment: thnax it works but one another problem came in picture that is view is not recognizing gesture properly

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the below method when you wants to bring the view to the front.

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:yourView];
```

Else

Create a view above the MkMapView and Dynamically Show/hide the view using the following:

```
[yourView setHidden:NO];
```

Comment: [self.view bringSubviewToFront:yourView]; But this didnt work

Comment: Try the another method of Hide/Show the view

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:yourView];
```

or

If you are adding your view in mapView,

```
 [mapView bringSubviewToFront:yourView];
```

If it does not work then please post some of your code.

Comment: [self.view bringSubviewToFront:mTimePickerView];